# Javascript Change picture on the go

Tags: javascript, concatenation

Updating the Question:
@Mouser, thank you for this answer. though I'm sure the code is fine, it actually doesn't do anything. I believe it is because I run the script right after the elements in the body section. So, the list is created, and then the code is run and the source of the listimgx changes, but how can I make it actually show the named src? At its current state, page loads, text items change, but the pictures don't. I tried adding a class to ul and adding a listview refresh at the end of my script, but it didn't work.

Original Question:
Ok, the following code is supposed to check a 2-dimensional-array value, and if it contains the string "fi", then it should change the i.th listimg.source to write.png.

In other words, the current img source is set to "mcicon.jpg". let's say, urlArray[4][1] contains "fi"; now I want listimg4.src to be "write.png". I'm trying a for loop for this, but it didn't work so far.I tried both these without success:
 
imgname.concat(i).src="write.png"
 
currentname.src="write.png"

```
//some items in my list:
<li>
<a href="#" onclick="datasent(1);"><img src="mcicon.png" id="listimg0" alt="Gummy Bears" /><span class="ui-li-count">12</span>
<h2 id="testname0"> Test Name 0</h2>
<p id="testexp0">Test Explanation 0</p>
</a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="#dog" onclick="datasent(2);"><img src="mcicon.png" id="listimg1" alt "Min Pin" />
<h1 id="testname1">Test Name 1</h1>
<p id="testexp1">Test Explanation 1</p>
</a> 
</li>
<li>
<a href="#gummies" onclick="datasent(3);"><img src="mcicon.png" id="listimg2" alt="Gummy Bears" />
<h1 id="testname2"> Test Name 2 </h1>
<p id="testexp2">Test Explanation 2</p>
</a>
</li>
```

```js
//and my javascript code:
<script>
var urlArray = [[1, "mc", "To Be Present", "Choose the correct answer.", 10, 0, 0],[2, "fi", "To Be Present", "Fill in the blanks using To Be Present.", 10, 0, 0]]

//those work:
document.getElementById("testname1").innerHTML = urlArray[1][2];
document.getElementById("testexp1").innerHTML = urlArray[1][3];

//this one does not work! the icon doesn't change!

for (var i=0; i<urlArray.length; i++) {
var imgname = "listimg";
if (urlArray[i][1]==="fi"){
  var currentname = imgname.concat(i);
  if(document.getElementById(currentname) ) //check if element exists
  {
     document.getElementById(currentname).src= "write.png";
     //for debugging; delete from production code.
     console.log(document.getElementById(currentname).src); //should write "write.png" to console.
  }
}
}
```

Comment: @UselessCode `String.prototype.concat` concatenates two strings together. And since JavaScript is a `weak typed language` it converts the integer `i` to a string and appends it to `imgname`. This can however be done more easily with `imgname + i`. However this can result in unwanted results, while concat will not.

Comment: @mouser True... however much like `Array.prototype.concat` returns a new array, [`String.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) returns a new string. That last line doesn't assign the new string to anything. Not used to seeing string `concat` being used, [it is much slower than using `+` or `+=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat#Performance).

Comment: @UselessCode That's why I removed that line in the code in my answer. It's concatenating a string, returns a new string and then calling upon the undefined property `src`.

Comment: When the `src` is changed the browser should automatically start loading the new image. Can your post you new code.

Comment: updated code. rechecked everything, but still it doesn't work. I changed one of the image sources manually, and it works then. so I believe the whole thing is caused by that I run this code at the end of the page (after the page loads those parts) this is all I can think of. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will not work. You're requesting the src property on a `string`. That isn't an image element. `document.getElementById("testname1")` maybe. So set the `src` of that element to `currentname`.

```js
urlArray = [[0, "si"], [1, "wi"], [2, "fi"]];

for (var i=0; i<urlArray.length; i++) {
    var imgname = "listimg";
    if (urlArray[i][1]==="fi"){
      var currentname = imgname.concat(i);
      if(document.getElementById(currentname) ) //check if element exists
      {
         document.getElementById(currentname).src= "write.png";
         //for debugging; delete from production code.
         console.log(document.getElementById(currentname).src); //should write "write.png" to console.
      }
    }
}
```

```html
<img src="" id="listimg2" />
```

Comment: This won't work for me, I'm afraid. I'm trying to check through a list of lists with the for loop. if the loop finds the "fi" value, it should change the img src for that sublist. your line: document.getElementById("testname1").src= currentname; sets the testname1.src to another image, but I need vice versa: I need to specify the testname1.

Comment: @ugur which img needs to be changes and what is the id of the img?

Comment: ok. for example, if the "fi" is found when the i=2 in the loop, listimg2.src should be changed to "write.png". Then, if the "fi" is also found at i=8, listimg8.src should be "write.png". that's why I'm trying to loop..

Comment: Do you have another solution for the updated question part? thanks.